# SyntaxError: Unexpected token with Jasmine

Tags: node.js, jasmine, webpack-2, jasmine-node

I'm using the latest node and running jasmine tests on my project only to be met with

> jasmine-node spec
>   Exception loading: /usr/src/app/spec/playground/playground.spec.js
>   /usr/src/app/src/engine/playground.Soundcloud.js:1 (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import PLAYGROUND from 'playground.js'
>   SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

my package.json is

```
{
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "server-server": "nodemon index.js",
    "dev" : "",
    "test": "jasmine-node spec",
    "dev-browsersync": "webpack-browser-sync --webpack false --proxy http://0.0.0.0:8000/",
    "dev-webpack": "webpack-dev-server --progress --colors --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000  & npm run debug-webpack",
    "start": "webpack --progress --watch",
    "debug-webpack": "node_modules/.bin/weinre --boundHost -all-",
    "postinstall" : "npm run server-server | npm run start"
  }
  "devDependencies": {
    "jasmine":"*",
    "browser-sync":"*",
    "jasmine-await":"*",
    "jasmine-node":"*",
    "request":"*",
    "webpack":"*",
    "nodemon-webpack-plugin":"*",
    "babel-core": "*",
    "babel-loader": "*",
    "babel-preset-env": "*",
    "babel-polyfill": "*",
    "babel-cli":"*",
    "jasmine-core":"*",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin":"*",
    "jasmine-expect":"*",
    "imports-loader":"*"
  }
```

What can be the problem here?

Answer (score 4):

Jasmine does not understand ES6. You'll need to transpile your specs to preset es2015.

Answer (score 0):

While using Jasmin `3.9.0` one day I suddenly received:

```sh
/path/to/node_modules/jasmine/lib/loader.js:39
  return import(path);
         ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

I was incorrectly using version `8` when I should have been using version `12`